# How to set up a database and API web page to accept POST updates from iPhone?

Tags: php, mysql, iphone, twitter

I am developing an iPhone app, which now can update Twitter account with GPS coordinates in real-time, by the Twitter API link: http://username:password@twitter.com/statuses/update.xml , and I am looking at how to make my own database to accept updates from iPhone, via a similar API page.

It seems a .php page can serve as the API, and MySQL can serve as the database.

What are the good ways of doing it? Any template code and tutorial please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/how-to-create-an-api-10-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I found the php page just need code like

```
$userid=$_POST["userid"];
$companyid=$_POST["companyid"];
$phoneid=$_POST["phoneid"];
```

to receive POST from the iphone app.